# ORA-00903: invalid table name while inserting record

Tags: oracle

```
Insert all into order(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id) values (70001,150.5,'05-Oct-2012',3005,5002)
           into order(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id) values (70009,270.65,'10-Sep-2012',3005,5002)
           into order(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id) values (70002,65.26,'05-Oct-2012',3002,5001)
           into order(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id) values (70004,110.5,'17-Aug-2012',3008,5002)
           into order(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id) values (70007,948.5,'10-Sep-2012',3007,5002)

select * from dual;
```

it showing error : `ORA-00903: invalid table name`

Answer (score 3):

`ORDER` is a reserved Oracle keyword. You can't name an object that without getting into trouble like this, as it interprets it as the start of the `ORDER BY` clause.

If you *must* use this table name, you can wrap it double-quotes, which tells Oracle it is definitely an object identifier:

```
 Insert all into "ORDER"(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id) values (70001,150.5,'05-Oct-2012',3005,5002)
           into "ORDER"(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id) values (70009,270.65,'10-Sep-2012',3005,5002)
           into "ORDER"(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id) values (70002,65.26,'05-Oct-2012',3002,5001)
           into "ORDER"(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id) values (70004,110.5,'17-Aug-2012',3008,5002)
           into "ORDER"(ord_no,purch_amt,ord_date,customer_id,salesman_id) values (70007,948.5,'10-Sep-2012',3007,5002)

select * from dual;
```

The double-quotes also make it case sensitive. So the above assumes you created the table in uppercase `CREATE TABLE "ORDER"....`. If you created it in lowercase, `CREATE TABLE "order"...` then you will have to use lowercase within the double-quotes instead.

However, you are *far* better off using a different table name.